# UNIX C HTTP request returning 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: c, http, unix, redirect, http-headers

I am familiar with the 301 error code but new to http requests and formatting them correctly.

In my program i need to retrieve my school's homepage, but i get a 301 Moved Permanently header. The header's location says where the page moved to, but even that new location won't work for me, probably because i didn't format it correctly.

Initially i send this request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.cs.uregina.ca\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n
```

And receive this header:

```
Received: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 04 Nov 2014 05:38:42 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.cs.uregina.ca/
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

What should my new HTTP request look like to get the above moved webpage?

If i try the location of the moved page like it suggests then i get the following 400 Bad Request Response:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: http://www.cs.uregina.ca\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n

Received: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Tue, 04 Nov 2014 05:52:36 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 334
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Initially i send this request:
>
> ```
> GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.cs.uregina.ca\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n
> ```
>
> And receive this header:
>
> ```
> Received: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
> ...
> Location: http://www.cs.uregina.ca/
> ...
> ```

This is exactly what I get when I request `cs.uregina.ca`. You have probably connected to `cs.uregina.ca` (or some subdomain other than `www`), or to an IP address the does not correspond to `www.cs.uregina.ca`.

> If i try the location of the moved page like it suggests then i get
> the following 400 Bad Request Response:
>
> ```
> GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: http://www.cs.uregina.ca\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n
>
> Received: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
> ...
> ```

This is not surprising. You must remove the `http://` protocol from the `Host:` header. Eg:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.cs.uregina.ca\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n
```

---

In general, when requesting a URL such as the following:

```
     http://domain.example:80/path/to/resource/?query#fragment
     ----   -------------- ==------------------------
   protocol      host      |        path
                          port
```

you would:

- resolve the **host** name to an IP address, and connect to that IP address on **port** (if present in the URL) or the default port associated with the **protocol**.
- Communicate with the server using a mechanism specific to **protocol**. In this case, an HTTP request.
- Request **path** from the server with an appropriate `Host:` header (in case there are multiple hosts on the same IP).
- The **fragment** identifier is used with (X)HTML and is not actually sent to the server.

The request should (at a minimum) look like this:

```
GET /path/to/resource/?query HTTP/1.1
Host: domain.example
Connection: close
```

---

The full details can be found in:

- [RFC 7230: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Message Syntax and Routing.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230)
- [RFC 7231: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Semantics and Content.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231)
- [RFC 7232: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Conditional Requests.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232)
- [RFC 7233: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Range Requests.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233)
- [RFC 7234: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Caching.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234)
- [RFC 7235: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Authentication.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235)

Comment: Very clear, thank you! I have one last question. If i need to form a request for the homepage of my professor, http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hilder/, would i find the IP address using gethostbyname("www2.cs.uregina.ca")? Because this function return an error of "Unknown host", so how do i know what the host name is to put in gethostbyname() when i need to request a webpage such as http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hilder/ ?

Comment: @shawna: I get `142.3.200.90` from here (Sweden). Are you sure you got everything right? Perhaps there was a temporary glitch, or not all of your name servers are correctly configured?

Comment: I got it figured out now, thanks Nisse. Best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the homepage, download nc and type "nc www.cs.uregina.ca 80"
When nc starts type the following and then hit return twice:

GET http://www.cs.uregina.ca HTTP/1.0

Comment: Actually, your request works fine with nc if you use the return key instead of \r\n.  I can only assume that the program you are using is escaping your back slashes and not interpreting the string as having carriage returns and new line characters.

Comment: I can only use my C program, no other software for this assignment.

Comment: Your request is formatted properly.  Make sure you are sending it to the correct server with the correct port.

Comment: Ah yes, i had the wrong hostname. I had cs.uregina.ca instead of the correct www.uregina.ca form. Solved, thanks!